# PHPUnit compare xml string with xml file failed in PHP 5.6, but pass in PHP 7.0

Tags: php, xml, symfony, phpunit

I use the travis-ci to run my tests. In my local computer I checked the two PHP version, and it is good. But in Travis the tests under 5.6 PHP version failed. But tests are passed in PHP 7.0 version. I do not know what is the real problem.

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/sitemap.xml');

$this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
$this->assertXmlStringEqualsXmlFile(
    __DIR__ . '/../Resources/sample.xml',
    $client->getResponse()->getContent()
);
```

I have a sample.xml which contains the correct XML structure with values.
I generate the sitemap.xml via /sitemap.xml link.

I always get error: The two DOM does not equal.

PHPUnit version is 5.1.3 on my computer.

Here the log file of Travis-ci:

```
$ php --version

PHP 5.6.5 (cli) (built: Feb 12 2015 01:41:10) 

Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

    with Xdebug v2.2.7, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans

$ composer --version

You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug

Composer version 1.2-dev (32a8a60695b9b9c9e2da01406ac3713903182669) 2016-05-17 13:08:17

before_install.1

0.00s$ if [[ ! $PHP = ${MIN_PHP%.*} && $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST != false ]]; then skip=1; fi

before_install.2

2.11s$ composer self-update --stable;

You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug

Updating to version 1.1.1 (stable channel).

    Downloading: Connecting...    Downloading: 100%

Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 32a8a60695b9b9c9e2da01406ac3713903182669

before_install.3

0.00s$ if [ "$SYMFONY_VERSION" != "" ]; then composer require --no-update symfony/symfony:${SYMFONY_VERSION}; fi

install

60.18s$ if [ ! $skip ]; then composer update --prefer-dist; fi

You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug

Loading composer repositories with package information

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

  - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.2.7)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.3.0)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.6.0)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.1.0)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/common (v2.6.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/polyfill-util (v1.1.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v1.4.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php70 (v1.1.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php56 (v1.1.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.1.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/symfony (v3.0.6)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-icu (v1.1.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing twig/twig (v1.24.0)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v3.0.16)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.5.4)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.5.4)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle (1.3.0)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.17)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (1.6.2)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.5.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/version (1.0.6)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/resource-operations (1.0.0)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/global-state (1.1.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.2)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/exporter (1.2.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/environment (1.3.7)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/diff (1.4.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/comparator (1.2.0)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (2.0.4)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (v1.6.0)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (3.1.3)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.8)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (1.0.0)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.8)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (3.3.1)

    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (5.1.7)

    Loading from cache

paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)

sensio/framework-extra-bundle suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (To use the PSR-7 converters)

doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle suggests installing symfony/security-acl (For using this bundle to cache ACLs)

sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)

phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing dflydev/markdown (~1.0)

phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing erusev/parsedown (~1.0)

phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (~1.1)

Generating autoload files

1.10s$ phpunit Tests/;

PHPUnit 5.1.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F....                                                               5 / 5 (100%)

Time: 973 ms, Memory: 28.25MB

There was 1 failure:

1) RepoSitemapBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testSitemapAction

Failed asserting that two DOM documents are equal.

--- Expected

+++ Actual

@@ @@

 <?xml version="1.0"?>

 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

-    <url>

-        <loc>http://www.localhosttest/1</loc>

-        <lastmod>2010-01-01</lastmod>

-        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>

-        <priority>0.9</priority>

-    </url>

-</urlset>

+                        <url>

+                <loc>http://www.localhosttest/1</loc>

+                <lastmod>2010-01-01</lastmod>

+                <changefreq>daily</changefreq>

+                <priority>0.9</priority>

+            </url>

+            </urlset>

/home/travis/build/botalaszlo/tmp-sitemap-bundle/Tests/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:37

phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.5/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:152

phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.5/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:104

FAILURES!

Tests: 5, Assertions: 10, Failures: 1.

The command "phpunit Tests/;" exited with 1.
```

But in PHP 7.0 this is not failed.
I have tried to load with SimpleXml the sample.xml file, but I had the same problem.

Short solution does not run tests in PHP 5.6

Answer (score 0):

That is because the string from your output and the string in your file contains spaces and new lines that are not equal to each other.

If you use phpstorm and run your unittest in there. You could see the differences and compare them. Phpstorm will show you a diff window by clicking on the assert error message in the console.

Comment: Thank you, but if I use the DomDocument, then preserve whitespaces = false, did not work too. I have no any idea. It is very tricky.

Comment: You really have to outline the xml to be exactly the same. No extra whitespaces or tabs